# Redmine 2.5.1 - can't see the new status although it's added to workflow

Tags: redmine, status

Having a problem with new status not showing up. Status is added to workflows, I can see new statuses on Agile board, but can't move issues to them on Agile board, and when editing issue status the regular way - new status is just not there. I thought maybe new settings are only applied to new projects - but no, still no new status visible. Any idea? Search didn't help me much. Thanks!

Comment: Did you give the proper permission to the affected user role for that status?